# Measuring volumes and displacement of a sphere contained in a pyramid

Tags: geometry, spherical-trigonometry

This is an interesting question.
[image]

The side view of the model is on the left. A solid sphere of radius 15 cm is contained inside a pyramid.  If the sphere touches all 5 faces of the pyramid, and water is injected into the pyramid such that half of the pyramid is filled. What is the volume of water is injected?

I am stuck!
When it says half of the pyramid is filled, does it mean that water level is up to one half of the pyramid's height? I have already calculated that the height is 40 cm.

Comment: Half the pyramid filled probably means half the volume is filled.

Comment: If it means the water level is up to one half of the pyramid's height, then how do I calculate the volume of water inside the pyramid?

Comment: Lucky enough that the 3 data points are not contradicting:) You do not need the 20 measure. The definition of half pyramid and relation to the sphere needs some clarification. The sphere volume is excluded from the pyramid (I assume?)

Answer (score 0):

HINT.
You must compute the volume of the frustum (which is $7/8$ of the whole pyramid) and subtract the volume of the spherical cap (the sphere cut at 20 cm from the base).